# How to find out that external database is updated in Django (while manage=False)

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

I have  a project that is connected to an external database and just have view access to it. So I created my models with `managed=False` flag.

I was wondering how can I find out in django that any change in that database is happened. Is there any solution in django or I should find a method to communicate between that database and my django app. like socket, database triggers and ...?

**More details:**

Image my models is like this:

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Meta:
    managed = False
```

Now i want to be notified in django each time the database is updated. I want a signal to capture database updates and do something in django?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215104/calling-an-url-from-a-trigger-in-mysql) seems related. Or, to clarify, you could set up a view in django that, upon request, will get "the new stuff" from db. Then in your DB set up a trigger to call that view... just an idea.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that before. But I read it again. maybe find a way to solve my problem from it.